# Trouble running Move Cursor Macro

Tags: vba

So I found this code to move my cursor every minute. It runs but after a minute I receive the error message:

> Ambiguous Name Detected: Move Cursor.

What am I doing wrong?

```vb
Private dtmNext As Date

Private Type POINTAPI
    x As Long
    y As Long
End Type

Private Declare Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (Point As POINTAPI) As Long
Private Declare Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer) As Long

Sub Move_Cursor()
    Dim Hold As POINTAPI
    GetCursorPos Hold
    SetCursorPos Hold.x + 30, Hold.y
    dtmNext = DateAdd("n", 1, Now)
    Application.OnTime dtmNext, "Move_Cursor"
End Sub

Sub Stop_Cursor()
    Application.OnTime dtmNext, "Move_Cursor", , False
End Sub
```

Comment: You have more than one thing called `Move_Cursor`?

Comment: @GSerg Thanks. But I am still not sure what to change.

Comment: Make sure you only have one thing called `Move_Cursor`? Or provide a more qualified name instead of just `"Move_Cursor"` when calling `.OnTime`?

Comment: @GSerg Changed the name of the sub to: Move_Cursornow and it is working. Thanks